# Programmatically assign Text_Changed event method to call

Tags: c#

I have a project I am working on and want to be able to call a method for all the controls whenever the text changed event gets fired.  I want to do it programmatically.  I have a linq query that returns all the controls on the form and I want to create a TextChanged event that runs a method for all those controls.

Comment: `textbox.TextChanged += (s, e) => { //here goes your code  };`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? And if yes, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"textBox1_TextChanged" is a function name, which you want to call when textchange happens.

```
textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
```

Update: function sample

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: please also add the code for `textBox1_TextChanged` otherwise it will throw an error

Comment: The shorter version: `textBox1.TextChanged += this.textBox1_TextChanged;`

Comment: it worked.  I created a linq statement to query the form and then recursed through adding the items.textBox1_TextChanged thanks